# Parse non-standard Date/Time format to Date in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date, ms-word

I have many strings of text preceded by a timestamp with the form

```
Oct 19, 2011, 5:00:40 AM GMT
```

I tried using isDate to check if some subset of the string is a Date, but the only section that seems usable is

```
Oct 19, 2011
```

and I would like to have the time data as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are cleaner ways to do it but this might help you get by:

For Date value enter (shown in cell B2): `=DATEVALUE(MID(A2,1,FIND(",",A2,FIND(",",A2)+1)-1))`

For Time value enter (shown in cell C2): `=TIMEVALUE(MID(A2,FIND(",",A2,FIND(",",A2)+1)+1,12))`

Results:

[image]